# Is this correct way to double each element of an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for (element of array){
  array[array.indexOf(element)]= element*2
}
console.log(array)
```

This is the code I wrote for doubling each element of an array but the output I’m getting is
(6) [8, 2, 12, 4, 10, 6]

What is the mistake I’m making?

Could someone please tell the logical error that I am making here .

Comment: do you expect a mutated array? or a new array with doubled values?

Comment: On the first iteration, you doubled the first element: `[2,2,3,4,5,6]`. Then on the second iteration, `array.indexOf(2)` is the first element, so you doubled it again `[4,2,3,4,5,6]` ...

Comment: btw, `indexOf` returns the index of the first found value. assigning a value to the same array does not help for `indexOf` without start index for searching. in this case by mutating the array is a standard loop with iterating over the index and omit `indexOf`.

Answer (score 3):

The first time around the loop you read the first item and get `1`, then you find the first index which has the value `1` and you change it to `2` which leaves your array looking like: `[2,2,3,4,5,6]`

The second time around the loop you read the second item and get `2`, then you find the **first** index which has the value `2` and you change it to `4` which leaves your array looking like: `[4,2,3,4,5,6]`

… and so on.

---

Use a classic for loop and work based on the index.

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  array[i]= array[i]*2
}
console.log(array)
```

Also consider using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and overwriting `array` with a *new* array with the doubled values.

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
array = array.map(value => value * 2);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to use your syntax, you could have cloned the array to fix.
However, this answer is just for the example. It's better to use solutions posted by Quentin.

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
let clonedArr = [...array];
for (element of clonedArr){
 array[clonedArr.indexOf(element)]= element*2
}
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the collection of possible alternatives: if you really want to change the original array values then the following would work too:

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
array.forEach((_,i,a)=>a[i]*=2)
console.log(array)
```

Comment: array.forEach((element,index,arr) => arr[index] = element*2); will probably more redable for a new contributor, but it's nice if you want to avoid map()! Good job!